# PHP parsing using libxml

Tags: php, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have simple XML file, where needed data has XML tag attribute field, e.g. named `type` with value `html`:

```
...
  <content type="html">Actual content</content>
...
```

When I try to parse this string into PHP object with `simplexml_load_string($my_xml_string, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA)`, I got this structure for part in question:

```
"content"=> array(
  "@attributes" => array("type" => "html"),
  "0" => "Actual content"
),
```

How do I parse that **all node attributes are skipped**, so in my example the object would be:

```
"content"=> "Actual content",
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The closest part that you can get is cast value to string, something like:

```
$my_xml_string = '<rt><content type="html">Actual content</content></rt>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($my_xml_string, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$str = (string) $xml->content;
echo 'content: ' . $str;
```